# Standard ML: BubbleSort with Arrays

Tags: arrays, functional-programming, sml

I'm trying to implement bubblesort using arrays but am having a tough time doing so.  Here's what I have so far:

```
fun swap(A, i, v) = 
    let 
        val temp = sub(A, i);
    in
        update(A, i, sub(A, v));
        update(A, v, temp)
    end;
```

This takes constant time so all good so far.

exception Empty;

```
fun bubbleSort(nil, i) = raise Empty
    (* if has one element, already sorted)
    | bubbleSort(
    (* if at least two elements, compare *)
    | bubbleSort(A, i) = 
        if i < A.length then
            if sub(A, i) > sub(A, i+1) then
                swap(A, i, i+1)
            else bubbleSort(i+1);
```

1) Now, this will only go through an array of >= 2 elements once.  But the bubblesort algorithm continues until you no longer need to swap elements and I'm not sure how to implement that recursively.

2) How do we pattern match on an array of length 1?  With a list it'd just be `bubbleSort([x])`...

Any help implementing would be awesome,
bclayman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your first question, one approach would be to add an extra parameter to your `bubbleSort` function which determines whether or not you have reached a fixed point.  Your function will then have the following type

```
bubbleSort : int Array -> int -> bool -> int Array
```

In each iteration, if you actually perform a swap, then set the flag to true.  Once you have gone through the entire array, then check if the flag has been set, and if so, reset `i` to 0.  Keep repeating this process until you make it all the way through without setting the flag.

Pattern matching on arrays is not something that is typically done, you can do it for vectors (see [this](http://www.smlnj.org/doc/features.html) link, note that this is SML/NJ specific), however, you are probably better of just using the length function instead.  This way, there isn't even any need to split up your first two cases.  You can simply check is the length less than 1, and if so, return the array without doing any swaps.

Comment: Arrays and vectors are not the same thing in SML, so the second part of your answer is not quite accurate. Furthermore, vector pattern matching is not a standard feature of SML.

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan, you are correct, I've edited my answer accordingly.  Thanks

Comment: @Matt but if I check if the length is one, then I think I'll run into trouble when it gets to the last element of the list and calls bubbleSort on it.   B/c then it'll be a list of length 1, and it'll return the array.  But it won't necessarily be sorted (it'll only have gone through the array once, not checked any flag re: whether a swap occurred)...

Comment: I think that you might be mixing up arrays and lists.  For example, you will get a type error with what you provided in your question as `nil` is of type `int list`, and `A` is of type `int array`.  Remember that you are not shortening the length of the array on recursive calls, you are only advancing the integer, that determines the next position to process.  Therefore, even when you get to the end of the array, `Array.length A` will always be the same.